# SSIS Excel Destination Nothing Happens when I hit New for Name of Excel Sheet

Tags: ssis, ssis-2016

I have an Excel file that does not exist. I am hoping to create the excel file and worksheet; however, the "New..." button does not work when I click on it. All it does it make the "Excel Destination Editor" screen disappear.

The Data Access mode is set to "Table or View".

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did seem to have success when I switched to 97-2003 format.